# Border bottom not overlapping border left

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I am developing an interface CSS, and I came across the following problem:

When I set the size of the border on the left larger than the others, it does not overlap the bottom edge of.

In this case the bottom edge of the edge overlaps the left green!

```
#contactList > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
    border-left:10px solid green;
    border-right:1px solid #999999;
    height:55px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/24/

Comment: What is embroidery? Why all the ellipsis?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, what is wrong with how your fiddle looks?

Comment: The bottom edge of the list, from left edge overlaps the green look!

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the border the ul element and not on the li element ;)

```
#contactList {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
border-left: 10px solid green;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but unfortunately it did not work. Unless I've done wrong, you can edit and save this jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, but looking good is not what I need ... : (I need the edges are individualized and each list item having a different color, as if they were a status (Online, Busy, Away). Thank you for your reply

Comment: interest if the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225593/border-over-borders-css-list-ul