# Border over borders CSS List <ul>

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-lists, border

I am facing a problem with edges in a css list (`<ul>`,`<li>`). The problem that when I set the left edge with a color and a different thickness, the lower edge of overlapping ends as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

In the picture there to see the right, so here I leave the fiddle to anyone who can give me help in this situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/31/

```
#contactList > li {
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
**border-left:10px solid green;**
border-right:1px solid #999999;
height:55px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is normal, borders reaches each other to the corners.

you may draw your line with box-shadow:
http://jsfiddle.net/T6KrE/32/

```
#contactList > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0 -2px  3px -2px gray;;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);

    border-left:10px solid green;
    border-right:1px solid #999999;
    height:55px;
}
```

Comment: hey man, that was exactly what I needed :). I had seen something about it, but did not quite understand how it worked .. thank you!

Comment: you re welcome! , play with box-shadow to handle their use , you can even draw things like : http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-digicode :)